# React Lifecycle Method not Triggered

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code which works fine except that my lifecycle method **componentWillLoad()** seems not to fire.

(please find componentWillLoad in the middle of second code snippet)

**My Code:**

1) index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Home, BookCourse} from './app/components/App'
import { CityChoice } from './app/components/CityChoice'
import { Form } from './app/components/Form'
import { Kurse } from './app/components/Kurse'
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

function reducer(){
  return 'State';
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component = { () => <Home/>} />
          <Route path="/cityChoice" component = {CityChoice} />
          <Route path="/kurse" exact component = {Kurse}/>
          <Route path='/lehrer-spezialisten' component={ () => window.location = 'http://lehrer-spezialisten.de'}/>
          <Route path='/bookCourse' exact component = {Form} />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

2) CityChoice.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class CityChoice extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={}
  }

  componentWillLoad(){
    console.log('Marc');
  }

  render(){
    const courses = _.map(this.state.courses, (course) => {
      return <li>{course.venue}</li>
    })
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Wähle Deine Stadt</h2>
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: 'Freiburg'}}>.      <Button>Freiburg</Button></Link></p>
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: 'Karlsruhe'}}><Button>Karlsruhe</Button></Link></p>
        <ul>{courses}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected behaviour**

a console output of "Marc"

**Actual Behaviour**

no console output "Marc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lifecycle method called `componentWillLoad`.

There is instead `componentWillMount` / `componentDidMount`.

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is
>   called before `render()`, therefore calling `setState()` synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the `constructor()` instead for initializing state.

Since React **16.3** `componentWillMount` is **deprecated** and you can use `componentDidMount` instead.

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of a `componentWillLoad()` unless that is some recent addition to React lifecycle methods.

Try it again, except this time use `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class CityChoice extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('My component was rendered to the screen');
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('My component was just updated...it re-rendered!!');
  }

  render(){
    const courses = _.map(this.state.courses, (course) => {
      return <li>{course.venue}</li>
    })
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Wähle Deine Stadt</h2>
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: 'Freiburg'}}>.      <Button>Freiburg</Button></Link></p>
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: 'Karlsruhe'}}><Button>Karlsruhe</Button></Link></p>
        <ul>{courses}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Save it and head over to your browser and pull up your console and you should see that you have both console logs outputted. The first console log will be from the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method and it will be called anytime your component shows up on the screen. The second lifecycle method you may or may not see console logged depending on whether your application is running a process such as a call to get your current geographical coordinates for example, then you will see the results of the `componentDidUpdate()` along with the first one. Otherwise, until you interact with the application which executes `setState()`, for example choosing a city or whatever your app does.

Technically, before `componentDidUpdate()` executes, the `render()` method will be called. So anytime your component updates, your `render()` method will be called which renders the jsx and right after that `componentDidUpdate()` will be called.